# Website Integration and inserting data into two different objects

Tags: webservices, website-integration

I'm fairly new to Salesforce coding but familiar with the admin tasks.

Here is what I'm supposed to do - 
I have a webpage (Wordpress site) through which a user can subscribe to various products.

On clicking on "Subscribe" - A record should be inserted into Contacts object and a record should be inserted into a custom object with the ContactID and Product Code (that would be passed from the webpage)

Would creating a Web-service help? How?

I am still exploring how to make a web-service call from Wordpress, but if you have any idea let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to create a public REST web service and host it in a Salesforce site. The method would access the new contact data and product code. It could then insert the Contact and related custom object in one transaction.

The Wordpress site could then use JavaScript to call the Rest web service.

A potential issue with this approach is opening the web service up to the public. You will want to consider how to secure it from unwanted submissions.